# h:selectManyListbox required attribute not triggered - JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, required, selectmanylistbox

The following code does not cause the component to be required:

```
 <h:selectManyListbox id="id" size="10" value="#{bean.emptylist}" 
  required="true" requiredMessage="Required">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.listofvalues}" var="var"
        itemLabel="#{var.val1 - #{var.val2}" itemValue="#{var}" />
 </h:selectManyListbox>
 <rich:message id="msg" for="id" styleClass="required"/>
```

On clicking submit, no message is displayed.

Comment: How are you submitting the `<h:form>`?

Comment: @luiggi <h:commandbutton>.

Comment: You need to add more context to your code. Many things could cause the form submission to fail. Backing bean code, nested forms etc

Comment: You have an error in the EL for itemLabel, where you probably wanted to do: `itemLabel="#{var.val1} - #{var.val2}"`. Is this the same code you are trying to make it work?

Comment: @kolossus, I isolated the <h:selectManyListbox> component on a separate page just to test it. The required attribute still does not work.